# Don't understand what Gulp is telling me

Tags: sass, npm, vagrant, gulp

I am currently following along in the series on Laracasts called "Build Larabook From Scratch" and on the 6th episode we have to compile a scss into css.

I'm trying to use Gulp to compile scss to css, on a vagrant box (as per the series).  However, when I run the command `sudo npm install gulp gulp-sass gulp-autoprefixer --save-dev`, I get the following  output (which doesn't seem to be what I want):

```
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.

> node-sass@0.9.3 install /home/vagrant/larabook/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass

> node build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing

|

․․․․․․․․․․․/

24 passing (112ms)

Binary is fine; exiting

gulp@3.8.7 node_modules/gulp

├── tildify@0.2.0

├── interpret@0.3.5

├── pretty-hrtime@0.2.1

├── deprecated@0.0.1

├── archy@0.0.2

├── minimist@0.2.0

├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.1, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)

├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)

├── semver@3.0.1

├── gulp-util@3.0.0 (lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.8-1.2.3, lodash.template@2.4.1, vinyl@0.2.3, through2@0.5.1, multipipe@0.1.1, lodash@2.4.1)

├── vinyl-fs@0.3.6 (graceful-fs@3.0.2, strip-bom@0.3.1, vinyl@0.3.2, mkdirp@0.5.0, through2@0.5.1, glob-watcher@0.0.6, glob-stream@3.1.14, lodash@2.4.1)

└── liftoff@0.12.0 (extend@1.2.1, minimist@0.1.0, resolve@0.7.4, findup-sync@0.1.3)

gulp-autoprefixer@0.0.8 node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer

├── bufferstreams@0.0.2 (readable-stream@1.0.27-1)

├── gulp-util@2.2.20 (lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.8-1.2.3, chalk@0.5.1, vinyl@0.2.3, minimist@0.2.0, lodash.template@2.4.1, multipipe@0.1.1, through2@0.5.1)

└── autoprefixer@2.2.0 (fs-extra@0.10.0, postcss@2.1.2, caniuse-db@1.0.20140810)

gulp-sass@0.7.2 node_modules/gulp-sass

├── map-stream@0.1.0

├── gulp-util@2.2.20 (lodash._reinterpolate@2.4.1, dateformat@1.0.8-1.2.3, vinyl@0.2.3, minimist@0.2.0, chalk@0.5.1, lodash.template@2.4.1, through2@0.5.1, multipipe@0.1.1)

└── node-sass@0.9.3 (object-assign@0.3.1, node-watch@0.3.4, mkdirp@0.3.5, nan@1.0.0, chalk@0.4.0, shelljs@0.2.6, node-sass-middleware@0.2.0, optimist@0.6.1, sinon@1.9.1, mocha@1.18.2)
```

I don't know if this is an error or not.  But, I do know that I can't compile the css still, and it isn't the output the video showed.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you got is not an error message, it's simply the log of the `npm install` of your modules.

The first part is the compilation of the [**node-sass**](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) library based on the C version of Sass which is used by your **gulp-sass**. As you can see, the build is passing and telling you the binary is fine.

The other part of the output is the summary of all the sub-dependencies **npm** just installed with their name and version that are needed by one of the module you want.

But there is some issues with your command :

1. You should not have to run `sudo`, since these modules will be installed in your current working directory.
2. The only sudo you need is with the command `sudo npm install -g gulp` to install it globally and be able to run `gulp` directly in your shell.

After this, all you need to do is create one Gulpfile which look like this (change the paths accordingly to you) :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

And finally run

```
gulp sass
```